# Local web server mirroring

Tags: web-server

I have a simple IP camera supporting only one client at a time, which is a raspberry Pi. I would like to set up a new web server on raspberry which will be performing something like a mirror to this server allowing me to connect more clients to it. Something like:

```
                                    / Client1
[IP Camera] --- [Raspberry Pi] ------- Client2
web server    "copy" the response   \ Client3
               from camera and        accessing RPi
              "paste" it on its       web server
               local web server
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Some details of the camera / software it uses will help...   if it needs a program on the client end I think you will be stuck.

Comment: It's an IP camera build on ESP32 AI Thinker providing only mjpeg stream. No special client program required.

Comment: Never tried it but this is in my bookmarks https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer but winter is here and the squirrels seem to have gone :-(   In my case I was planning on the onboard camera but you may be able to use the input_http module.

Comment: I think there are two big things you're trying to achieve here: syncing the Raspberry Pi with the camera's server AND setting up a server that can handle multiple connections. It's better if you can focus on one question at a time, so what would you like to do first?

Comment: I think that natural way is to sync camera server with rpi first, and then enable rpi server for handling multiple connections.

Answer (score 1):

There are services such as https://www.ipcamlive.com/ which can fetch the stream from your IP camera (or the Pi) and broadcast it to multiple users. The basic service plan is free.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the camera runs an actual HTTP web server, I think you may be looking to create reverse proxy server on the raspberry pi. In this case, the raspberry pi would create its own connection to the web camera and mirror the web server on the web camera on its own web server, where your clients can access it.

In this case, I’d recommend Nginx, it’s an easy and simple to use web server that supports this feature. You can read fully about Nginx and the reverse proxy feature here: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy/

Comment: NGINX willmake multiple upstream connections for each new client, this doesn't work with the camera server which streams mpeg and can only do so in 1 connection